Browser does not store Http Cookie from ASP.NET Web API Docker
I run ASP.NET web api project, a microservice in docker container. I have React + Vite app in another container. I´m trying to send an http cookie from that microservice to the fronted. I can see the cookie in the response in Set-cookie, however my browser refuses to store it (Application -> Cookies ), also the cookie ins not present in a request.
In my hosts file I have:
127.0.0.1 praxeosu.local
127.0.0.1 auth.praxeosu.local
 var cookieOptions = new CookieOptions
 {
     HttpOnly = true,
     Secure = true,
     SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
     IsEssential = true,
     Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(3),
     Domain = "auth.praxeosu.local" //note I also tried praxeosu.local or with dot at beginning - no success
 };

Appending to the request in endpoint:
Response.Cookies.Append("Bearer", result.Data.Token, result.Data.Cookie);
return Ok();

My CORS setup
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAll",
        builder => builder.AllowAnyMethod()
                            .WithOrigins("https://praxeosu.local", "https://praxeosu.local:5001", "https://auth.praxeosu.local:5001")
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowCredentials());
});

In the React I use axios and I have set withCredentials to true.
My NGINX:
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name praxeosu.local;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/praxeosu.local.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private/praxeosu.local.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256";
    
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
}

# NGINX konfigurace pro Authorization Service API
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name auth.praxeosu.local;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/praxeosu.local.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private/praxeosu.local.key;


    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256";
    

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://authorizationservice:5001;
        proxy_set_header Host auth.praxeosu.local;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

I have self signed certificates and browsers do not have problems with them and it is shown that the frontend is running on secure https (same for the backend when i open swagger)
However the browser still does not save the cookie, and I dont know where else the problem can be.
Mybe its stupid question, but I am novice regarding the cookies, react and nginx
Thank you,
Lukas
I tried to change the domain in the cookies, change the SameSite mode etc. browser still refuses to save the cookie, and send it back with requests.

Please show us the raw HTTP response's headers, including the Set-Cookie header. Your browser (i.e. Chrome or Firefox) should print a message to the "Issues" pane (not the Console, surprisingly) if it drops cookies, often with an explanation.

Are you using the domain= parameter to enable subdomain cookie-sharing? If so, you shouldn't rely on that functionality because it likely will stop working entirely when browsers introduce stricter per-origin partitioning: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Privacy/Privacy_sandbox/Partitioned_cookies

@Dai
response headers:
access-control-allow-credentials:
true
access-control-allow-origin:
https://praxeosu.local
api-supported-versions:
1.0
cache-control:
no-cache,no-store
content-length:
0
date:
Sat, 09 Nov 2024 19:08:21 GMT
expires:
Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
pragma:
no-cache
server:
Kestrel
set-cookie:
Bearer= placeholder for token as its too long to place here; expires=Sat, 09 Nov 2024 22:08:21 GMT; domain=auth.praxeosu.local; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly
vary:
Origin

...you shouldn't be using Set-Cookie to pass around a Bearer token.

... yea i have read about that.. Im going to change that in the future, but first I need to resolve the problem with cookies not being stored, once I will know where I do the mistake then I am going to implement better solutions about the authorization.. Its just my university work

SOLUTION:
I was totally blind as the react did not tell a word.
Solution was this:
const response = await axios.post('/api/v1/auth/login', { email: `${email}@osu.cz`, password: password }, { withCredentials: true });

I had to move the withCredentials into separate brackets.
The original code was this:
const response = await axios.post('/api/v1/auth/login', {
    email: `${email}@osu.cz`,
    password: password,
    withCredentials: true
});

Note the difference. Maybe it will help someone as blind as me, no offense :)
Thank you,
Lukas
